# How does compiler handle missing parameter names in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, selector

I have run into someone else's code that declares methods like this:

```
- (void) method:(id)a:(NSString*)b { }
```

The compiler accepts this code, giving just a warning:

```
'a' used as the name of the previous parameter rather than as part of the selector
```

The code declares various functions with this type and then invokes them through NSSelectorFromString, using the signature "methodname::". So it's all consistent.

I wonder if that method signature is just a mistake or if there's more to it. Since it's used consistently in the code, I don't think this is a typo. I don't know the author so I can't tell if this is code of a genius or the opposite.

Is 'b' an anonymous parameter? (If so, shouldn't it rather be written with a blank between the "a" and ":" to indicate this better?) I can't find anything about anon parms in the ObjC docs, though.

Will there be any change in behavior if I change the syntax to giving the second parameter a name, and fixing the signature reference accordingly? I plan to make this change to get rid of the warnings, but I wonder I might create an issue that I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything you describe is pretty much correct. It's very bad style, but technically it's just a two-argument selector which happens to have no text before the second `:`. I wouldn't call `b` an anonymous argument since you can still give it a name, it just doesn't have any descriptive text before it as part of the selector's name.

Yes, there should probably be a space after the `a`.

If you want to rename it, you can use Xcode's standard Refactor->Rename functionality and just insert some text before the second `:`. It will update all the references and you should encounter no problems.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Though, I sure doubt that the refactoring engine will be able to detect the selector strings used by NSSelectorFromString.

Comment: Why is the code using `NSSelectorFromString`? You should use `@selector()` where possible.

Comment: You're making wrong assumptions. The code generically builds the selectors from text strings.

Comment: Also, please explain why you think it's not anonymous? ObjC's method calling style names parameters (contrary to almost any other popular programming language), so not naming one makes it anonymous, doesn't it? When I call the method, I can't give it a name, or do you mean I can write "[self method:@"a" secondArg:@"b"]" despite the 2nd parm not having a name?

Comment: I was actually thinking from the perspective of the selector implementation. You can reference the second argument by `b`, so technically it has a name. But I guess you're right that as far as 'named arguments' goes and from the perspective of the caller, there is no name. I'm not sure if there is standard terminology for this case.

Comment: Ah, OK. In other words: The formal parameter is named but the actual parameter is anonymous. If you're update your answer in this regard, I'd happily give you the "correct answer" :) Well, you'll get it anyway, just asking that you remove the ambiguity from your answer. In fact, what threw me off was that you used "argument" - the argument is what gets passed to a function. You mean formal parameter.

Comment: It seems that the terminology is "unlabeled argument", see page 16 in [The Objective-C Programming Language](http://examples.oreilly.com/9780596809775/ObjC.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

You *can* use the signature `method::`, even though it is not recommended by most people.
Just insert a space character before each `:` separating the parameters, and the compiler is happy:

```
- (void) method:(id)a :(NSString*)b
```

On page 16 "Message Syntax" of [The Objective-C Programming Language](http://examples.oreilly.com/9780596809775/ObjC.pdf)
this is called an *"unlabeled argument"*, or an *"argument without keyword"*.

Of course you can change it to

```
- (void) method:(id)a withB:(NSString*)b
```

but this changes the selector to `method:withB:`.